# Java OutputStream.write() throws Bad file descriptor but flush works

Tags: java, ioexception, outputstream

I am writing code that uses a file Stream reversible like this

```
public static void writeBlock(OutputStream stream, float[] data, byte startPosition)
{
   int i = 0;
   for(i = startPosition; i < data.length; i++)
   {
      // Code
      stream.flush();
      stream.write(someByte); // throws Exception at second call
      if(someCondition)
      {
        break;
      }
   }
   stream.flush();
   if(i < data.length)
   {
      writeBlock(stream, data, i)
   }
}
```

I am getting `IOExceptions` with the message: `Bad file descriptor`

The method is getting a `FileOutputStream`.

But how can the file descriptor be bad if it works the first time.
Where is my Problem?
Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Why all the flushes? Never flush inside a loop. Put one at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself

I opened another Stream (BitOutputStream) in the method that writes to `stream`and closed this bitStream afterwards.

```
public static void writeBlock(OutputStream stream, float[] data, byte startPosition)
{
  int i = 0;

  //Bitstream bitstream init

  for(i = startPosition; i < data.length; i++)
  {
     // Code
     stream.flush();
     stream.write(someByte); // throws Exception at second call
     if(someCondition)
     {
        break;
     }
  }
  bitstream.close();
  stream.flush();
  if(i < data.length)
  {
     writeBlock(stream, data, i)
  }
}
```

After I deleted that line (`bistream.close()`) it worked.

Comment: The reason this failed was because your `BitOutputStream` was wrapped around the `FileOutputStream`, so closing the first closed the second.

Answer (score 1):

`flush()` depends on the implementation of OutputStream being used. The abstract OutputStream class implementation of this method does nothing. If the OutputStream subclass never buffers output, it will most likely not implement this method and `flush()` will do nothing. Even if `flush()` does something for the implementation that was passed if there is no buffered output it is very likely to just return immediately.

There is something wrong with the file passed to the OutputStream. Would need more information to figure  out what the issue is.

Comment: yeah the flush at first is not necessary but i wanted to show that it works.
But how should i solve that problem? my problem is that write() throws an exception

Comment: @AlexanderWohltan The default implementation of `flush()` does nothing, so unless a subclass overrides it (such as `FileOutputStream` does)...

Comment: I don't care about the `flush()`.
It is overwritten by FileOutputStream

Comment: At least in openjdk 8 it is not http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/io/FileOutputStream.java#FileOutputStream

Comment: What Infos do you need? My code is very long and I think it is easier to explain but if you want the code I'll post it.

Comment: @AlexanderWohltan `FileOutputStream` has never had an override of `flush().`